# How can I extract messages from .sbf file

Tags: sony-ericsson-xperia-x10

I have backed up my messages from my Sony Xperia, and now I want to open the file and export them to excel or something more easy to read, but I can't find a program or tool to do that I just have the file and i want to open it and extract specific information. I need some help, thanks!